# TypeError: pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color

Tags: python, seaborn, iris-dataset

```
sns.pairplot(df,hue='target')
```

I can plot the pairplot using the pairplot function. but i want to plot it using the facegrid function.i tried

```
sns.FacetGrid(df,hue='target').map(sns.pairplot,hue='target').add_legend()
```

but this line gives me error that pairplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'.
can we plot the pairplot using facegrid function?.

Comment: I have the same with 'corner', this doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I had this issue with 'corner' as well. Turns out I was using v0.9.0 where this keyword hadn't been implemented yet.